# Discord.Py - Logging whenever a guild is chunked on startup

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to log whenever a guild is chunked on my bots start up. This currently works, however id like to be able to know the total amount of guilds that my bot is in, before the bot is ready.

The current log looks like this - `Chunked guild guild.name`

However, I'd like to display some other information such as: `Chunked guild guild.name (1/200) (meaning 1 out of 200 guilds has been chunked)

```
@property
def chunked(self):
    """:class:`bool`: Returns a boolean indicating if the guild is "chunked".

    A chunked guild means that :attr:`member_count` is equal to the
    number of members stored in the internal :attr:`members` cache.

    If this value returns ``False``, then you should request for
    offline members.
    """
    count = getattr(self, '_member_count', None)
    print(f"Chunked guild {self.name}")
    if count is None:
        return False
    return count == len(self._members)
```